# java.lang.RuntimeException crash on Android startup

Tags: android

I'm having an issue with my Android app where it doesn't open on any device with any version of Android. A few of the devices and OSes are

HTC One M8 on 4.4.4,
Samsung SM-N910V Galaxy Note 4 on 6.0.1,
SM-G930V Galaxy S7 on 7.0,
Huawei P9 on 6.0,
Huawei Y560 on 5.1.1,

The app works fine on iOS and it does run in the Android Studio emulator. All the crash reports are the same. Here's a screenshot of one crash.

[image: Screenshot of crash report]

**Note** I'm not a programmer

Runtime.java - this code has java.lang.Runtime in it

```
public void loadLibrary(String libname, ClassLoader classLoader) {
checkTargetSdkVersionForLoad("java.lang.Runtime#loadLibrary(String, ClassLoader)");
java.lang.System.logE("java.lang.Runtime#loadLibrary(String, ClassLoader)" +
" is private and will be removed in a future Android release");
loadLibrary0(classLoader, libname);
```

android/MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0; // Used for OSU count
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_ID = 1; // Used for other messages
    private static final Locale LOCALE = java.util.Locale.getDefault();

    private static volatile OSUService sOsuService;

    private ListView osuListView;
    private OsuListAdapter2 osuListAdapter;
    private String message;

    public MainActivity() {
```

appwithspaces/MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ActivityMainBinding mBinder;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinder = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(mBinder.getRoot());
```

multimoduletestapp/MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ActivityMainBinding mBinder;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinder = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(mBinder.getRoot());
    }

    public ActivityMainBinding getBinder() {
        return mBinder;
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView mListView;
    private final BitmapCache mCache = new UnrefedBitmapCache(TARGET_CACHE_SIZE_BYTES, 0, 0);
    private final DecodeAggregator mDecodeAggregator = new DecodeAggregator();

    private static Drawable PLACEHOLDER;
    private static Drawable PROGRESS;

    private static final float NORMAL_PARALLAX_MULTIPLIER = 1.5f;
    private static final int TARGET_CACHE_SIZE_BYTES = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
```

That's what I've been able to found so far for MainActivity. I hope I'm heading in the right direction.

Comment: Please de-obfuscate the stacktrace

Comment: How do you have more than one MainActivity? Which one does the Manifest load?